# 2 way ssl with Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, pki

I want to implement two way ssl for a domain. For testing purpose, I am trying to use the same certificate (certificate issued for my domain) for client authentication.

I have added follwing directives to nginx -

```
    ssl_client_certificate /root/certs/web_in.crt.bundle;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

The bundle has one intermedite CA and a root CA.
Then I converted the certificate to pfx format using following command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in web_in.crt -certfile web_in_ca-bundle
```

I added this file to chrome browser.

Now when I am trying to hit the url using chrome, I get ssl certificate error. I am pasting the logs from nginx in debug mode. Nginx is complaining that certificate is not truested but I am unable to figure out why is it so. I have alreadyverified the certificate using openssl.

`2019/04/01 18:42:24 [debug] 17710#0: *3520 http header done
2019/04/01 18:42:24 [info] 17710#0: *3520 client SSL certificate verify error: (27:certificate not trusted) while reading client request headers, client: 115.99.57.64, server:
 ninjadev14.slicepay.in, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "ninjadev14.slicepay.in", referrer: "https://ninjadev14.slicepay.in/"
2019/04/01 18:42:24 [debug] 17710#0: *3520 http finalize request: 495, "/favicon.ico?" a:1, c:1`

Comment: Take a look at [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/758964/client-ssl-certificate-verify-error-27certificate-not-trusted) over on Server Fault.